# Bundle VueJS Components to use same data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm trying to figure out how I can bundle some Components which use the same data (from an API) so I only need to make one call. I'm learning VueJS right now and I don't know if this is even possible or how it is called. So basicly what I'm trying to archive is this:

Create an `index.js` file which get's the data from the API and bundles the components which use this data (or parts of it).

Useing `import {subComponent} from '@/components/bundle/'` to get a specific component from that bundle while it uses the data delivered by `index.js`

Is this possible? Probably this is common but I don't know what it's called. How can I realize this?

So far I tried this:

*view.vue*:

```
<template>
    <subComponent1/>
</template>
<script>
import {subComponent1} from '@/components/bundle';

export default {

    name: 'view',
    components: {
        subComponent1
    },

</script>
```

*index.js* (in `components/bundle/`):

```
<script>
import subComponent1 from './subComponent1'
import subComponent2 from './subComponent2'

export {
    subComponent1 ,
    subComponent2 
}

</script>
```

The Components are standart single-file components and don't use data from index.js yet, but I'm already getting this error:

[image: Image_of_failure]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's when VueX comes into handy: you store the data in a global store, and all your components can have access to it.

Comment: I'm trying to prevent using vuex since these components are only needed in a single view and I don't want to spam my vuex store. Instead I'd like to have something like a seperate vuex store in index.js, which doesn't affect the actual vuex store.

Comment: If the data is readonly, you probably don’t even need to store using Vue. What about sessionstorage?

Comment: You can load the data in [`$root`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-the-Root-Instance) and access it from there.

Comment: You have problem in your vue-router config file. Can you show us what you have there?